# angular+oidc-client: getUser() always returns null

Tags: angular, oidc-client

I am using oidc-client in my angular project. I have written the below code in app.component.ts to redirect user to home page if user object is not null. But the user object is always null even after successful login. I am using microsoft azure to authenticate.

**app.component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.authService.getUser().then(user => {
        console.log(user) // always returns null even after login
        if (user) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
    });
}

login() {
    this.authService.signinRedirect();
}
```

**AuthenticationService.ts**

```
export class AuthenticationService {
    
    private userManager: UserManager;
    constructor(settings: Settings) {
        this.userManager = new UserManager(settings);
    }

    public signinRedirect() {
       this.userManager.signinRedirect();
    }

    public getUser() {
        return this.userManager.getUser();
    }
}
```

I dont see any key:val pair in local/session storage named oidc.user.xxxxxxx after successful login.

Also, I crosschecked with some sample in-house applications. After a successful login, oidc api is triggering a call to token endpoint. In my case this end point is not being called.

What could be missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which module AuthenticationService is provided, also if you can post UserManager code?

Comment: I have only one module. UserManager is from oidc-client library.

Answer (score 1):

Registering a signin redirect callback in app.component.ts solved this issue.

```
async ngOnInit() {
if (window.location.href.includes('code')) { // without this if condition I am getting an error saying no state in response. not sure if there is a better way.
     this.authService.signinRedirectCallback();
}

await this.authService.getUser().then(user => {
    console.log(user) // always returns null even after login
    if (user) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
});
```

}